# Different seven-digit numbers could Sid have meant to type

Tags: combinatorics

> Sid intended to type a seven-digit number, but the two 3's he meant to
>   type did not appear. What appeared instead was the five-digit number
>   $52115$. How many different seven-digit numbers could Sid have meant to type?

First time, I attempted this problem as follows-

I considered, there are 12 places available for two 3's (as they can appear together)

_ _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _

So, we can select 2 places from 12 places in ${12\choose 2}$ = $66$ ways.

But, I found the correct approach is simply choosing 2 places from available 7 place in ${7\choose 2}$ = 21 ways. However, I can't find my mistake in previous one. Can anyone explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following possibilities:

_ 3 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1_ _ 5 _ 3

_ 3 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1_ _ 5 3 _

3 _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1_ _ 5 _ 3

3 _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1_ _ 5 3 _

All of these would give the same result of 3521153, but are counted separately by your first method.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive explanation is:

Consider 6 _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _, we have $6$ places to put the next $6$:

6 6 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _

6 _ 5 6 _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _

6 _ 5 _ _ 2 6 _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _

6 _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 6 _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _

6 _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 6 _ 5 _ _

6 _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 6 _

Continuing:

_ _ 5 6 _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _ gives $5$ (different from before) places

_ _ 5 _ _ 2 6 _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _ gives $4$

_ _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 6 _ 1 _ _ 5 _ _ gives $3$

_ _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 6 _ 5 _ _ gives $2$

_ _ 5 _ _ 2 _ _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ 5 6 _ gives $1$

Adding these, $6+5+4+3+2+1=21$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer 21 is got as follows: If the threes are together then we have 6 numbers (choosing one of the 6 gaps in 52115. If the threes are not together, we need to pick two places out of 6 and this can be done in $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ ways. Thus a total of 21 numbers.